# Headless Chrome hangs when trying to print page as PDF

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, headless

At our organization we use headless-chrome for converting web pages into PDFs.
We have a special Java application for that, that uses the following CDT client for launching the chrome instances and communicating with them: https://github.com/kklisura/chrome-devtools-java-client
In most cases everything works as expected and we get our PDFs, but for some web pages headless-chrome just hangs during the PDF printing step.
Example of such page:

```
https://www.idc.com/cee/events/64662-web-developers-event-for-automatic-tests-on-idc-com-do-not-update-manually/print-agenda
```

We were not able to get any useful logs from the headless instances of chrome, even though we followed all the necessary steps specified here: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging
We tried to debug those headless instances using the --remote-debugging-port option, but we didn't find anything suspicious in the console or anywhere else.
The page appeared to be loaded successfully and it seems that chrome just refused to print the pages.

Did somebody else have similar issues? Or maybe somebody has any idea as to why does it happen? Maybe somebody has some tips on how to enable the logging on the headless instances of chrome?
We will be grateful for any help.

Here are the versions of applications:

```
Google Chrome: 76.0.3809.100
chrome-devtools-java-client: 1.3.5
```

Thanks!
Max.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the underlying websocket API implementation, Tyrus. It has a [default maximum message size of 4MB](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/tyrus/blob/3a43614646a11a7c9b440997350af203f8f2f1cb/client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/client/TyrusClientEngine.java#L80). This URL, and many others (especially if you enable printing backgrounds), results in PDFs that (when encoded as base 64) are larger than that 4MB limit. In this case the websocket is closed with a [Buffer overflow error](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/tyrus/blob/3a43614646a11a7c9b440997350af203f8f2f1cb/core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/core/Utils.java#L323), however we don't see it as `chrome-devtools-java-client` [doesn't listen to the websocket's `onClose` events](https://github.com/kklisura/chrome-devtools-java-client/blob/196992f40d1e26f0a31cf0fe7b99ba607297d0e0/cdt-java-client/src/main/java/com/github/kklisura/cdt/services/impl/WebSocketServiceImpl.java#L101).

You can resolve this problem by streaming the print result instead...

Pass the `PrintToPDFTransferMode.RETURN_AS_STREAM` as the `transferMode` parameter to `Page.printToPdf` and then read from the stream with a buffer significantly less than the 4MB limit (even after the increase due to base 64). I use 1MB:

```java
private static final int READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 1048576;
```

```java
final PrintToPDF printToPDF = page.printToPDF(..., PrintToPDFTransferMode.RETURN_AS_STREAM);

final IO io = devToolsService.getIO();
int offset = 0;
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    do {
        final Read read = io.read(printToPDF.getStream(), offset, READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (read.getBase64Encoded() == Boolean.TRUE) {
            byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(read.getData());
            offset += decode.length;
            fos.write(decode);
        } else {
            byte[] decode = read.getData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            offset += decode.length;
            fos.write(decode);
        }

        if (read.getEof() == Boolean.TRUE) {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
}
io.close(printToPDF.getStream());
```

I'm not sure about the `offset` treatment in the case where the result isn't base 64 encoded, but I don't think we're going to see that when printing!

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was! Thank you very much!